# String.replace adding extra characters

Tags: vb.net, string, outlook-addin

I am trying to replace some words in mails in Outlook. Here is my code for it

```
        Dim input As String = mail.HTMLBody
        Dim pattern As String = "QWQ[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"
        Dim replacement As String
        Dim rgx As New Regex(pattern)

        Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(input, pattern)
        While (match.Success)
            replacement = "A" + match.Value + "A"
            input = input.Replace(match.value, replacement)
            match = match.NextMatch()
        End While
        mail.HTMLBody = input
```

For this input

```
QWQrt12345
QWQrt1234533

wwQWQrt12345
QWQrt1234534

qwwQWQrt12345
```

I expect output as

```
AQWQrt12345A
AQWQrt12345A33

wwAQWQrt12345A
AQWQrt12345A34

qwwAQWQrt12345A
```

But the output I am getting is

```
AAAAAQWQrt12345AAAAA
AAAAAQWQrt12345AAAAA33

wwAAAAAQWQrt12345AAAAA
AAAAAQWQrt12345AAAAA34

qwwAAAAAQWQrt12345AAAAA
```

What can be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description of [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) states,

> Returns a new string in which all occurrences of a specified string in
>   the current instance are replaced with another specified string.

The important takeaway there is, "**all** occurrences ... are replaced." Since your replacement string is also a match for your regular expression pattern, it will be replaced (thus adding another set of 'A') upon every iteration.

Try a test case using something like this, instead:

```
        replacement = match.Value.Replace("Q", "A")
```

The details here don't matter (you can change whatever you want), the point is that you change *something* so that your strings aren't matched repeatedly.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Justin ! I am now using this approach to get the expected output

input = input.Replace(match, "XSDEGTHYI")
input = input.Replace("XSDEGTHYI", replacement)

Answer (score -1):

simply put your adding 'A' + match + 'A' evertytime you match .

Resulting in the AAAAA before and after your input. I've been voted down?

ok I explain your first match input result is exactly what you have inputted(all characters could be matched), you then add "A" both sides and want to replace your replaced value with the original value.

Here's the c# code to get expected value :

```
        var input = "QWQrt1234533"; //your second line example
        const string pattern = "QWQ[a-z][a-z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]";
        var rgx = new Regex(pattern);

        Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
        while (match.Success)
        {
            var replacement= "A" + match.Value + "A";
            input = input.Replace(match.Value, replacement);
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }
        Console.Write(input);
```

resulting in your exected : "AQWQrt12345A33"

not getting your results even with the posted VB code (you did not edit the original after my first response?)

Comment: Sorry did not get it. Can you please provide the right code changes?